# the URL for the request may be different than that of the reply?

Tags: qt, http, pyqt, pyside, qnetworkaccessmanager

in the doc of QNetworkReply::request() says 
"In special, note that the URL for the request may be different than that of the reply."

I wonder What factor(s) can cause the difference ?

Note : The Network Access API does not by default follow redirections: it’s up to the application to determine if the requested redirection should be allowed, according to its security policies.

Comment: One common case I could think of is requesting `http://foo/` and getting `http://foo/index.html` etc.

Comment: I requested http://qt-project.org but QNetworkReply::request() still replies http://qt-project.org.